# Jquery div reload affects other parts of my page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

so quick and to the point...

im making a delete post script for my practice cms.

When clicking on delete, i dont want to have the page reload but instead just have the div removed. To do this i do the following:

```
$("#postholder").load("pageurl.php?id=5 #postholder");
```

Now, this works fine and looks great. But it stops all of the scripts working on the page.

In my eyes, only that div should be reloaded, but it means that if i go to delete another post, i have to refresh my page for it to work again.

Where am i going wrong?

Also whilst im here, how can i change "pageurl.php?id=5" to just by the current page url.

So what can i replace it with so it works on what ever page as it just uses the current url.

Thanks <3

Comment: could you post the code you have for when the delete button is clicked? Do you have something like $('.delete').click(); ?

Answer (score 0):

How about [removing the DIV from the DOM](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)?

```
$("#postholder").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your click handler doesn't work with dynamically loaded content. Assuming you are using jquery version >= 1.7 you can use the .on() method to listen on ajax loaded content.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
    $("#postholder").load("pageurl.php?id=5 #postholder");
});
```